# How do I amend missing values to 0 when using full_join function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rlang, multidplyr

I have an issue with the below code and the error corresponding to the code. Can someone help?

Trying to run the below matrices that are defined-

```r
ESL <- full_join(ES_Liquidity, ES_Liquidity_prev, by = "Institution");
ESL_SMBPN <- full_join(ES_Liquidity_SMBPN, ES_Liquidity_SMBPN_prev, by = "Institution");
ESL <- full_join(ESL, ESL_SMBPN, all = TRUE, by = "Institution");

table1 <- full_join(SC, ESL, by = "Institution"); # join where institution matches 
table1_Revised <- full_join(SC_Revised, ESL, by = "Institution")
```

Errors that I'm getting outlined below-

```
1. <error/rlib_error_dots_nonempty>
2. Error in `full_join()`
! `...` must be empty.
x Problematic argument:
* all = TRUE
```

Any advice?

Trying to get the data read in the entire script. I'm trying to collate a dataframe with certain types of assests for e.g. ABS, covered bonds, central government bonds etc. Some of these assets have null values (0). Script isn't able to read it I believe?

The graph has x variables (i.e. ABS, Agency etc) but not all of them are in every month, especially now that collateral levels are very low, there are far less categories. Believe the graph doesn't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Delete `all = TRUE`. That is an argument for `merge()`, not for `full_join()`.

Comment: Just a sidenote, why not using `ELS <- Reduce(\(x, y) full_join(x, y, by = "Institution"), list(ES_Liquidity, ES_Liquidity_prev, ES_Liquidity_SMBPN, ES_Liquidity_SMBPN_prev))`

Comment: HI @MerijnvanTilborg, thanks for that. this works too. can you explain what did you do again sorry? cant quite understand what you did there.

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas, thanks that worked on my system. However, my colleague who uses the same code on his system, uses all=TRUE in the same argument for full_join() and it works on his system. Why would that be the case? just want to understand it a bit better, if you could let me know please?

Comment: @aaliad, it is one of the "apply" functions where it loops over your lists and applies a function over x and y, then the result is stored in x and that function is then applied over that previous result. For example `Reduce(intersect,list(a,b,c))` is the same as `intersect((intersect(a,b),c)`

Comment: `full_join` is in the `dplyr` package. Maybe in an older version it allowed unnecessary arguments like `all = TRUE`, and now it doesn't.